# Different library conflict with same name file

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I encounter a series of file conflict with my SBT build file.I'm pick two error of them which represent properties conflict and class conflict.

The error caused by `sbt assembly` command, as this:

```
error] (util/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/lorancechen/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-buffer/jars/netty-buffer-4.0.42.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] /Users/lorancechen/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-common/jars/netty-common-4.0.42.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] /Users/lorancechen/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-codec-http/jars/netty-codec-http-4.0.42.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] /Users/lorancechen/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-codec/jars/netty-codec-4.0.42.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] /Users/lorancechen/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-transport/jars/netty-transport-4.0.42.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] /Users/lorancechen/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-handler/jars/netty-handler-4.0.42.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] /Users/lorancechen/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/jars/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.42.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/lorancechen/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/Log.class
[error] /Users/lorancechen/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.2.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/Log.class
```

It not caused by library version dependency conflict but because of different library has same class or file named with same package path.

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible fetch correct file and how to do it in sbt build file?
2. Java project should be follow the package namespace definition. So, why the two organization of `org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j` and `commons-logging/commons-logging` has the same class path `org/apache/commons/logging/Log.class`, rather then define as `org/slf4j/commons/logging/Log.class` for `org.slf4j` org and `org/apache/commons/logging/Log.class` for `commons-logging` org?
   Besides, the name of `commons-logging` as a groupId is very strange.

Thanks.